# Are finder tags case-sensitive?

Tags: filesystem, finder-tag

OS X Mavericks introduced file tagging to Finder and the filesystem. Are these tags case-senstive? For example, could I have an `Apple` and `apple` tag?

Comment: What happens if you give it a try?

Comment: @patrix When entering/searching for a tag it preselects an existing one even if they are a different case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

I am able to seemingly tag files with differently cased words by opening the `Get Info` window on each file in Finder. However after I save and close each window and inspect the tags for each file the tag that was saved first overrides the other differently cased tag.

- Note: this is with the default case-insensitive filesystem. I have not tested this on a case-sensentive filesystem.